URL luego de confirm se queda en la web que lo contiene para cumplir otra condición
La segunda vez la URL dentro de la segunda condición no sé por qué no redirige a ella y simplemente se queda en la web donde está el script, es decir: como esta comprobación solo permite ingresar por día un solo test, este sí abre perfecto luego del confirm, por lo cual al ser realizada la comprobación redirige a la segunda url (notas), pero al momento de realizar el confirm y darle aceptar no redirige a esa url notas.php sino que se queda en la web donde está el script.
if($cargo=="CONDUCTOR"){
    if($hays ==1){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            if (confirm(nombrejs+", Deseas agregar notas tecnicas a este vehículo?")) {   
             return true;                
                window.location.href = "https://pagina.com/fichero/notas.php?conductor="+nombrejs+"&ident="+identjs+"&cargo="+cargojs+"&fecha="+fechajs+"&hora="+horajs+"&codigg="+codigojs+"&placa="+placajs;
            } else {
           return false;
        }
        });
    </script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            if (confirm(nombrejs+", no has realizado el test a tu vehiculo asignado, deseas realizarlo?")) {
                window.location.href = "https://pagina.com/fichero/test.php?conductor="+nombrejs+"&ident="+identjs+"&cargo="+cargojs+"&fecha="+fechajs+"&hora="+horajs;
            }else{
           return false;
        }
        });
    </script>';
    }
}


Excorpion me ayudó con este script el cual funciona perfecto y le agradezco mucho, pero ahora no sé por qué pasa esto.

lo he hecho asi no se si me corrijen si notal algun error..
llamo las funciones desde php segun cada condicion:
if($cargo=="CONDUCTOR"){
if($hays ==1){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    confirmationnotas();
</script>';
}else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  confirmationtest();  
</script>';
}
}   

estas son las funciones..
function confirmationnotas(){
        if(confirm(nombrejs+", Deseas agregar notas tecnicas a este vehículo?")){
            window.location.href = "https://pagina.com/fichero/notas.php?conductor="+nombrejs+"&ident="+identjs+"&cargo="+cargojs+"&fecha="+fechajs+"&hora="+horajs+"&codigg="+codigojs+"&placa="+placajs;
       return true;
        } else {
       return false;
    }
     }
     
     function confirmationtest(){
        if(confirm(nombrejs+", no has realizado el test a tu vehiculo asignado, deseas realizarlo?")){
            window.location.href = "https://pagina.com/fichero/test.php?conductor="+nombrejs+"&ident="+identjs+"&cargo="+cargojs+"&fecha="+fechajs+"&hora="+horajs;
       return true;
        } else {
       return false;
    }
     }


El DOM content loader, es solo para la carga. Si quieres ejecutarlo nuevamente, tienes que hacerlo como lo tenias, sin el DOM y llamar la función de otra manera.

recuerda, uno es para llamarlo apenas carga la página, y el otro para llamarlo cuando lo necesites y desde donde lo necesites

¿Has mirado que pasa si quitas el return true; que tienes antes de la redirección?

Hola mil gracias, si he quitado el return true,
